# Content-Disposition header and Cyrillic filename

Tags: http, http-headers

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cyrilic_filename.ext"');
```

is it possible somehow to set that it's an UTF-8 name? Or I'm to convert filename to ASCI?

Comment: That this question have been already asked over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but doesn't work for all browsers yet. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/, http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5987.html, and http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-content-disp-latest.html.